# Find date sequence in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2014, sqldatetime

I'm trying to find the maximum sequence of days by customer in my data.
I want to understand what is the max sequence of days that specific customer made. If someone enter to my app in the 25/8/16 AND 26/08/16 AND 27/08/16 AND 01/09/16 AND 02/09/16 - The max sequence will be 3 days (25,26,27).

In the end (The output) I want to get two fields: custid | MaxDaySequence

I have the following fields in my data table:
custid | orderdate(timestemp)

For exmple:
`custid  orderdate
1   25/08/2007
1   03/10/2007
1   13/10/2007
1   15/01/2008
1   16/03/2008
1   09/04/2008
2   18/09/2006
2   08/08/2007
2   28/11/2007
2   04/03/2008
3   27/11/2006
3   15/04/2007
3   13/05/2007
3   19/06/2007
3   22/09/2007
3   25/09/2007
3   28/01/2008`

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a Gaps and Islands problem -- https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/ I have written these queries before and they make my head hurt!

Comment: also, what results are you expecting from the sample data you provided?

Comment: @aron -- they don't seem that hard you just have a row number and subtract that number of days.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick, if you have an incrementing number ordered by your date then a subtracting that number of days from your dates will be the same if they are consecutive.  So like this:

```
SELECT custid, 
       min(orderdate) as start_of_group,
       max(orderdate) as end_of_group,
       count(*) as num_days
FROM (
   SELECT custid, orderdate
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY custid ORDER BY orderdate) as rn
) x
GROUP BY custid, dateadd(day, - rn, orderdate);
```

You could take the result of this and pull out the max number of days to solve your problem:

```
SELECT custid, max(num_days) as longest
FROM (
  SELECT custid, 
         count(*) as num_days
  FROM (
     SELECT custid, orderdate
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY custid ORDER BY orderdate) as rn
  ) x
  GROUP BY custid, dateadd(day, - rn, orderdate)
) y
GROUP BY custid
```

Comment: Hi Hogan, Thanks for that. Great answer. Simple and effective. I think I will add in the first subquery a DISTINCT on the 'orderdate' field. Because same customer can enter more than one time in a day to the App.

Comment: And how to do this in MySQL? (Without ROW_NUMBER())

Comment: @AsSAASA - your question is tagged sql server -- is this actually a mysql question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it with MySQL:

```
select user_id,max(num_days) as longest
from(
select user_id, count(*) as num_days
from
(
SELECT    (CASE a1.user_id 
           WHEN @curType 
           THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
           ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := a1.user_id END
          ) AS rank,
          a1.user_id,
          a1.last_update as dat
FROM      (select a2.user_id,left(FROM_UNIXTIME(a2.last_update),10) as 'last_update' 
                from visits as a2 group by 1,2) as a1 ,
            (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r

ORDER BY  a1.user_id DESC, dat) x
group by user_id, DATE_ADD(dat,INTERVAL -rank day)
) y
group by 1
order by longest desc
```

Comment: After some rank value, DATE_ADD will return null